Unable to show message in Kafka consumer
I am reading yahoo finance API to get multiple stock prices and sending it to kafkaProducer that is working properly.
code is as below
 import yfinance as yf
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
from confluent_kafka import Producer, Consumer

DELAY = 1.0  # Time between calls in seconds.

def get_stats(ticker):
   info = yf.Tickers(ticker).tickers[ticker].info
   print(f"{ticker} {info['currentPrice']}")
   p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})
   p.produce(ticker, info['currentPrice'])
   p.flush()  


def call_API(event):
   ticker_list = ['DLF.NS','SBIN.NS']

   with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
      executor.map(get_stats, ticker_list)

   event.set()  # Signal call has been made.

print('Running')
event = threading.Event()
while True:
   event.clear()
   timer = threading.Timer(DELAY, call_API, (event,))  # Call after delay.
   timer.start()
   event.wait()  # Blocks until event is set by another thread.

I want to read values of all topics in consumer that is not working
   from confluent_kafka import Consumer
   c = Consumer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': "stock"})
   c.subscribe(['DLF.NS','SBIN.NS'])

   while True:
       msg = c.poll(1.0)

   if msg is None:
       continue
   if msg.error():
      print('Error: {}'.format(msg.error()))
      continue

   print('Received message on {}: {}'.format(msg.topic(), msg.value().decode('utf-8')))

What changes should i mede to get met all topics data in consumer

Your print statement and if checks should be within the while loop. Otherwise, you're endlessly polling and not processing any messages
